# How to implement imputation with Python script in Power BI?

Tags: python, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to run a validated Python script to impute data in PowerBI. The data is originally consolidated in Power BI, then exported to Excel, imputed and analysed with Python.

Now, I would like to use the code from Python into Power BI's query editor, so that I can get imputed data directly into Power BI and use its visualizations, but I get errors.

I tried pasting the same code I have in Python in Power BI - I think there might be an issue with the syntax.

```
dataset=#"PreviousStep"

import pandas as pd

byISO = dataset.groupby(['country ISO'])
byIG = dataset.groupby(['WBG Income Group'])
bytIG = dataset.groupby(['WBG Income Group','Year'])
bytR = dataset.groupby(['UN Sub-Region','Year'])

#Country-level
#Filling up and down
dataset[['col1','col2']] = byISO[['col1','col2']].fillna(
        method='ffill')
dataset[['col1','col2']] = byISO[['col1','col2']].fillna(
        method='bfill')
#Interpolation
dataset[['col1','col2']] = byISO[['col1','col2']]\
         .apply(lambda i: i.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside'))
#Extrapolation (FILLING DOWN CURRENTLY)
dataset[['col1','col2']] = byISO[['col1','col2']]\
         .apply(lambda i: i.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='outside'))
#Median
dataset[['col1','col2']] = byISO[['col1','col2']]\
    .transform(lambda i: i.fillna(i.median()))

#Group-level
#Median
dataset[['col1','col2']] = byIG[['col1','col2']]\
    .transform(lambda i: i.fillna(i.median()))
#Yearly median
dataset[['col1','col2']] = bytIG[['col1','col2']]\
    .transform(lambda i: i.fillna(i.median()))

#Region-level
#Yearly median
dataset[['col1','col2']] = bytR[['col1','col2']]\
    .transform(lambda i: i.fillna(i.median()))
#No level (All)
#0
dataset[['col1','col2']].fillna(0)
```

I expect a table with imputed values, but I get this error as a result instead:

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Python script error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, pandas, matplotlib.pyplot
  File "C:\Users\GEscamilla\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Details:
    DataSourceKind=Python
    DataSourcePath=Python
    Message=Python script error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, pandas, matplotlib.pyplot
  File "C:\Users\GEscamilla\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonScriptRuntimeException
```

Comment: Try to install `numpy` library

Comment: `import numpy`, If not installed please use `pip install numpy`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error output it is telling you

`ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`

This means that you have to import numpy along with your other import statements as @prathik says in the comment. You can find example here from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-python-scripts)

`import numpy`

If that does not work you need to make sure you need to install with

`pip install numpy`

***The bigger picture***

You should consider placing the script before the dashboard - so that the transformed data can be used by other dashboards as well.

Usually I would recommend making all data transformations in a Data Warehouse, or a mart for a specific purpose. However, this all depends on whether or not this a one-time exercise or something you are going to use in production.